# How can I quickly preview an image with a circular frame?

Tags: image-manipulation

Some images are displayed in a circular frame after uploading. For example, GitLab project icons:

[image: The swag suggestions image is displayed in a circular frame]

When tweaking an image on the desktop, I don't really know how it will look in a circular frame before I upload. For example, some elements might get cut off and I'll have to re-adjust the canvas size and try again.

How can I *quickly* preview a circle-cropped version of an image on the desktop?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Using something like the following example, you can create a *circle cropped* image.

```
convert original_image.png \
    \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 64,64 64,0" \) \
    -alpha off -compose copy_opacity \
    -composite circle_image.gif
```

Please refer to [How to make a image in desired shape in imagemagick?](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15492&p=54769&hilit=circle+mask#p54769) in ImageMagick forum for details.